# In irb, why is there a predefined variable "d"?

Tags: ruby, irb

For some reason there's a variable called `d` that is defined immediately after I enter irb. Any idea what it is?

Comment: Using `method` can help you work it out yourself.

Comment: Andrew, what do you mean 'using method' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using `irbtools` by any chance? If yes, there's a predefined method called `d`, that roughly looks like this:

```
def d
  self.tap { |v| puts v }
end
```

It can be used to debug message chains like this: `obj.some_method.d.other_method`.

Since it's defined at the `Object` level, it should work if you just call it at the IRB top level where it would return `main`.

Answer (score 4):

You can run `irb` with the `-f` switch to supress loading of `~/.irbrc`:

```
irb -f
```

This will quickly tell you if `d` is coming from somewhere in your `~/.irbrc` (which it most likely is - see Michael's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Not for me:

```
$ irb
>> d
NameError: undefined local variable or method `d' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
```